# Send 3 text box values to a server-side method with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send three text box values to server using jquery ajax. problem is that, i dont know the exact syntax to send three data. When i try sending one data(also change no.of parameters to one at server side method), its going good but when i try to send three text box values, its giving jquery error:"Internal server error". I think I am not sending data in correct way. please somebody tell me how to do that.

Below is the code:

```
function testCAll() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dbTest1.aspx/SendMessage",
    data: "{'name': '" + $('#Eid').val() + "', 'phone': '" + $('#phn').val() + "'}",
    //data: "{'phone': '" + $('#CustomerPhone').val() + "'}",
    //data: "{'color': '" + $('#ColorId').val() + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        resultData = eval("(" + result.d + ")");
        $("#rawResponse").html(concatObject(resultData));
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("jQuery Error:" + result.statusText);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your server-side code and not with your Javascript.

Comment: you are right, i have tried something to check if the problem is on server side or client side. now i have found out that problem is on server side. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

instead of how you encode data now, try doing this:

```
data: {'name':  $('#Eid').val(), 'phone': $('#phn').val() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one temporary object like this:

```
tempcustno = $("input[id$="cusnoid"]").val;
tempcustname = $("input[id$="custnameid"]").val;
tempcustdept = $("input[id$="custdeptid"]").val;

var jsonobj= {
    Custnumber:tempcustno,
    Custname:tempcustname,
    Custdept:tempcustdept
};

var sdata= JSON2.stringify(jsonobj);

$.ajax {
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:sdata,
    datatype:json,
    //----
}
```